# PDOStatement could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So price receives a double from the database and every time I try to execute this segment of the code or convert it I get:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string

```
try{    
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=janes_catering', $username,   
    $password); 
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $price = $conn->query("SELECT cost FROM foods WHERE description = 
    ':choice' AND size = ':oice'");
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT foods(description, size, cost) 
    VALUES ( :choice, :oice, :price)");
    $TPrice = (string)$price;
    $stmt->bindParam(':choice', $choice, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':TPrice', $TPrice,  PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':oice', $oice, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->execute();           
}
```

Comment: `$price` is an object. Read about `fetch_` methods and use them.

Comment: Mike, the structure of your code is wrong. First, you cannot get anything from the query prior executing it. Second, to get the price you have to fetch the value, using [fetchColumn()](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#fetchcolumn) method.